# HoughCircles finds wrong circles (opencv)

Tags: java, opencv, hough-transform

i have the following picture and what i actually want to detect is the circles above the box with letter to the top left of each box. But the result is that it detects also some other circles. I have no idea why.

Image that I want to detect on:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMPdA.jpg

This is what the result looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbREy.jpg

As you can see it can find letters as circles sometimes and also the circles on the lego. Here is my code:

```
Mat source = Highgui.imread("testar.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
            Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(), source.cols(), source.type());

            Imgproc.cvtColor(source, destination, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

            Imgproc.GaussianBlur(destination, destination, new Size(3,3),0,0); 


            Mat circles = new Mat();
            Imgproc.HoughCircles(destination, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, 10, 20, 7, 13);

            int radius;
            Point pt;
            for (int x = 0; x < circles.cols(); x++) {
            double vCircle[] = circles.get(0,x);

            if (vCircle == null)
                break;

            pt = new Point(Math.round(vCircle[0]), Math.round(vCircle[1]));
            radius = (int)Math.round(vCircle[2]);

            // draw the found circle
            Core.circle(destination, pt, radius, new Scalar(0,255,255), 3);
            Core.circle(destination, pt, 3, new Scalar(255,255,255), 3);
            }

            Highgui.imwrite("foundCircles.jpg", destination);
```

Comment: hough circle function seems to work as intended, since all it finds in your test image are some kind of circles. If you have some higher knowledge about the kind of circles you want to find, you should use it (test what kind of colors are within the circle, whether there is another letter inside the circle etc).

Comment: sorry, that looks very accurate to me

Answer (score 3):

Well, IMHO, the Hough Circle detection algorithm is working exactly the way it is supposed to be. It IS detecting circles.

However, it seems like you do not want to detect the circles lying outside the area of the mobile phone's screen.

A simple solution can be implemented if you somehow manage to lay your hands on the exact coordinates of the four corners of the phone (or the mobile screen).

You can use the Rect class to define a rectangular block:

```
Rect cropRect = new Rect(topLeft_X, topLeft_Y, widthOfRectangle, heightOfRectangle);
```

and then use this rectangle object to reproduce a new image matrix (from the original one) that contains only the desired area:

```
Mat croppedImage = new Mat(inputImg, cropRect);
```

Now, with the freshly cropped image by your side, you can have all the fun you want with the algorithm of Mr. Paul Hough.

---

Now, if for some reason, it turns out that you do not have any clue about how to get the coordinates of the four corners of the phone (i.e, the phone moves around whimsically), OR you're damn irritated with the Hough circle detection reporting the O's and S's as circles, then you may try seeking the help of any good OCR implementation to help ease your pain.

Since you're on Java, you may use [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/). Or, you may try tweaking [this project](http://javaocr.sourceforge.net/) to extricate the position of the characters in the mobile screen. (There are many other OCRs which might help, [please refer to this website for an exhaustive list](http://www.google.com))

Once you have the exact position of the characters, you may try running the Hough Circle detection block in the vicinity of the top left corner of the characters only.

*One word of caution though, OCRs tend to be a wee bit nasty and unwieldy in Java.*

---

If you're still unhappy with the results (or if OCRs seem to interfere with you metabolism), there's one last approach which you may try.... Hough Line detection.

Detect the lines, from the polar coordinates of the lines, estimate the grid that forms the keypad of the phone and then go around with detecting circles on the top left corner of the grids.